# Change ActiveRecord statement cache default Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a suspicion that my app is having a memory leak, I read about that rails is automatically managing cache of the last 1,000 query execution. Almost every query in my app is unique and pretty heavy and contains many rows returned.

So Is there a way I can change the default value of the statement caching?
(I'm using postgres DB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's handled at Database Adaptor Level. There is an option to configure it by `statement_limit` in Postgrsql adaptor.

you need to add it in `database.yml`

```
production:
adapter: postgresql
statement_limit: 200
```

Follow [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-postgresql-database) link for official documentation. There is an option to completely disable the statement cache.

```
production:
adapter: postgresql
prepared_statements: false
```

Secondly there is an option to clear the `statement cache` in postgres adaptor. There is a method named `clear_cache!` it can be found at [Postgres adaptor](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter.html#method-i-clear_cache-21)

[Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14645) is a very good discussion on this same matter. You will find all the details in following links

Answer (score -1):

Rails has a number of built-in caching strategies, but none of them are based on a *number of queries* per se. The cache, if limited, is based on the *file size* and *expiration time*.

If your application is using memory store, then the default file size limit is `32Mb`. This can be changed by adding the following line to your configuration:

```
config.cache_store = :memory_store, { size: 64.megabytes }
```

The official documentation on this, along with the many other forms of caching, can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memorystore).

Given your apparent need for such intensive caching, I would recommend you also look into various other options - such as [fragment cacheing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) and [Russian doll caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#russian-doll-caching) - as this could potentially be a far less resource intensive strategy than SQL caching alone.

Comment: I wish someone had added a comment while down-voting this answer.

Comment: @RN. Presumably because, as the accepted answer pointed out, there *is* a way to configure the number of prepared statements (for a Postgres database only, I think). However, this is still not really a "rails" config and the rest of my answer I believe is accurate - so I stand by the above advice.